# React native image background covers some components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using a HoC to set the background image for my components, however it seems like the ImageBackground component covers some of my elements. I tried setting the z-index to a negative number with no luck.

Here's the HoC:

```
const withBackgroundImage = Wrapped => {
  return props =>
    <ImageBackground source={ BackgroundImage } style={ { width: '100%', height: '100%', zIndex: -10000 } }>
      <Wrapped { ...props } />
    </ImageBackground>
}
```

And here is the wrapped component:

```
<View style={styles.root}>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={ match.url } component={ HomeView }/>
    <Route path={ `${match.url}/profile` } component={ ProfileView }/>
    <Route path={ `${match.url}/other` } component={ OtherView }/>
  </Switch>
  <View style={styles.bottom}>
    <BottomNavbar />
  </View>
</View>
```

The bottom navbar gets covered but the page rendered by the router has no problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot replicate this on both android and ios. Could you provide a PoC on expo snack?

Comment: It's the first time in having a go at a react-native app, so I haven't used expo snack before. Managed to recreate it here: https://snack.expo.io/ByLhoqXzI hope it will suffice.

Comment: @JustinCredible, you should try put ImageBackground  and BottomNavbar in same View.